# When can a team gain a bonus point in the Asia Cup?

Tags: cricket, tournaments

Pakistan gained a bonus point after defeating Afghanistan by 72 runs.

> They had mentioned during the match that Pakistan could earn a bonus
>   point if they stop Afghanistan to score 198 runs. - [sports.ndtv[08.49 (IST)]](http://sports.ndtv.com/asia-cup-2014/news/221367-asia-cup-2014-live-cricket-score-afghanistan-vs-pakistan)

- How is this score calculated? What formula is used for this?
- If the second batting team wants to gain a bonus point, how should the chase be?

Comment: Can a team get double bonus point??

Comment: @cricketfreak - There is no double bonus point for a single match. A team can get two bonus points in two games (one in each).

Comment: 7k+ views in just 4 days?? #Unbelievable

Comment: @hims056, views are arrived from [google search](https://www.google.co.in/search?site=&source=hp&q=asia+cup+bonus+point&oq=asia+cup+bonus+po&gs_l=hp.3.0.0i22i30l6.1799.7310.0.8766.17.15.0.1.1.0.181.1430.12j3.15.0....0...1c.1.36.hp..1.16.1439.I9LJMahXat0).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

From [the Point Table of Asia cup 2014](http://www.espncricinfo.com/asia-cup-2014/engine/series/671665.html?view=pointstable):

> #### Bonus Points
>
> The team that achieves a run rate of **1.25 *times*** that of the opposition shall be awarded one bonus point. A team's run rate will be calculated by reference to the runs scored in an innings divided by the number of overs faced.

So the formula is like this:

```
Run-rate to restrict opponent = Team batting first run-rate / 1.25
```

In that match Pakistan scored 248 runs with run rate of 4.96.

So run-rate to restrict Afghanistan = 4.96 / 1.25 = 3.968
So runs to restrict Afghanistan = 3.968 * 50 = 198.4 ~ 198.

**Note**: If a team is all out before 50 overs with high run-rate, the net run-rate shall be based on 50 overs:

From the Point Table of Asia cup 2014:

> In the event of a team being all out in less than its full quota of overs, the calculation of its net run rate shall be based on the full quota of overs to which it would have been entitled and not on the number of overs in which the team was dismissed.

For example, a team B (batting second, who need to score more than 198 runs to prevent team A from gaining the bonus point) is all out in 150 in 20 overs, their net run rate will be (150/50) 3 and not (150/20) 7.5.

> If the second batting team wants to gain a bonus point, How the chase should be?

The calculation is simple:

```
Required run-rate to gain a bonus point = required run-rate * 1.25
```

To calculate required run-rate:

```
Required run-rate = Target / 50
```

For example,

Team A scored 320 runs in 50 overs with run-rate of 6.4. If team B wants to win the match with bonus point:

```
Required run-rate = 321 / 50 = 6.42

Required run-rate for a bonus = Require run-rate X 1.25
                  = 6.42 X 1.25
                  = 8.025 runs per over.
```

Now the calculation of require overs to chase target is easy: 321/8.025 = 40 overs.

For more refer [Appendix 6 (Bonus Point System) <sup>*PDF*</sup>](http://static.espncricinfo.com/db/DOWNLOAD/100/0131/Bonus_Points.pdf).

---

#### Bonus: See the [Bonus Point Calculator](http://jsbin.com/yodul/6)!